# Why can I offer a bounty with a lesser amount than the last bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

Well, look at [this revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/155980/revisions). Nothing weird? If I'm not misinterpreting the bounty rules, the minimum reputation invested on bounties on a specific question are increased with each bounty.

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

I don't know if it's ambiguous but it feels like it is a general you (all users) instead of "the same user on the same question". Can someone clear this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thought that it is the general 'you', while plausible, is not correct. Instead, it refers to a *single* user placing a bounty multiple times.

This is to prevent individuals from cheaply keeping a question featured.

Any use of multiple accounts to avoid this would be considered misuse of multiple accounts.